# Data Preprocessing for KNN in python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-preprocessing

preprocessing take a lot of time-consuming to understand, tuple, list, float, array structure.
I have data that looks like

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of                                                       X                                 Y
0     [1.9902, 1.9902, 1.9902, 1.9902, 1.9902, 0.034...      [0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.094]
1     [1.9902, 0.034, 0.034, 0.034, 0.034, 0.034, 0....      [0.094, 0.094, 0.094, 0.094]
2     [0.034, 0.034, 0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.0...  [1.0882, 1.0882, 1.0882, 1.0882]
3     [0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.094, 0.094, 0.094, 0.0...  [1.0882, 1.2382, 1.2382, 1.2382]
4     [0.094, 0.094, 0.094, 0.094, 1.0882, 1.0882, 1...  [1.2382, 1.2382, 1.2182, 1.2182]
...                                                 ...                               ...
3395  [0.136, 0.286, 0.286, 0.286, 0.286, 0.286, 0.2...  [0.1276, 0.1276, 0.1276, 0.1276]
3396  [0.286, 0.286, 0.266, 0.266, 0.266, 0.266, 0.2...   [1.1423, 1.2923, 1.2723, 3.672]
3397  [0.266, 0.266, 0.266, 0.1276, 0.1276, 0.1276, ...      [3.672, 3.672, 3.772, 3.772]
3398  [0.1276, 0.1276, 0.1276, 0.1276, 1.1423, 1.292...      [3.772, 3.802, 3.802, 3.802]
3399  [1.1423, 1.2923, 1.2723, 3.672, 3.672, 3.672, ...      [1.021, 1.021, 1.021, 1.021]
```

I am doing data split using

```
x=csv_data['X']
y=csv_data['Y']
#print(x)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y)
```

Fitting to KNN model

```
K = []
training = []
test = []
scores = {}
  
for k in range(2, 21):
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
  
    training_score = clf.score(x_train, y_train)
    test_score = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
    K.append(k)
  
    training.append(training_score)
    test.append(test_score)
    scores[k] = [training_score, test_score]
```

Getting error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-906aa771beda> in <module>()
      6 for k in range(2, 21):
      7     clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
----> 8     clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
      9 
     10     training_score = clf.score(x_train, y_train)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have been trying few methods such as `preprocessing` or `StandardScaler` dint work for me.
Kindly help in running KNN.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while using `KNN` your `y` is of the shape `(n, 4)` while the  `KNN.fit` method wants your `y` to be of shape `(n,1)`. So in short you can only predict 1 value from `y`. So in short you either use `KNN` 4 times for each column in `y` or don't use `KNN`.

The code will be like this

```
# Import KNN for regression

y1 = y.iloc[:, 0]
y2 = y.iloc[:, 1]
y3 = y.iloc[:, 2]
y4 = y.iloc[:, 3]

regressor1 = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k).fit(x, y1)
regressor2 = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k).fit(x, y2)
regressor3 = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k).fit(x, y3)
regressor4 = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k).fit(x, y4)
```

OMG!! Now that I see you were using `KNN` for classification where in fact your problem is regression. Your fundamentals are really really poor.

Also, Just don't even use that. You won't get any good results from it and it's also computationally expensive.

Comment: also, it's coming same error for other methods as well. I tried to fit on the random forests as well. Same error when i fit the model.

Comment: That error will come in every model as you just CAN'T have your y as a matrix.

Comment: well, your code is not giving any output. I think you dint got my question.

Comment: @NIrbhayMathur I won't write the whole code for you. I gave your enough answer for your question. The the remaining code is same as yours. I just changed your `clf.fit(x_train, y_train)` line to 4  of  these `regressor1 = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k).fit(x, y1)` lines. So now you just need to use `training_score1 = regressor1.score(x_train, y_train)` and `training_score2 = regressor2.score(x_train, y_train)` and so on with the rest same.